# Trying to extract values from APi

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract all values of countries from api reponse, but getting an error during the extraction.

Error:string indices must be integers
Code:

```
covid_get = requests.get("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
##covid_get = requests.request("GET",url="https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
    covid_json = covid_get.json()
    ##covid_json = json.loads(covid_get)
    logger.info(covid_json)
    for value in covid_json:
        b = value["Countries"][0]['Country']
        print(b)
```

Can someone please help here ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace? I expect the issue is exactly what it says... The indices of a string must be an integer. I expect `value[”Countries"][0]` is a string. If the API request is working fine this question doesn't have anything to do with the request, just working with the data. See this post on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this in python3

```
import requests
covid_get = requests.get("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")

covid_json = covid_get.json()
countries = covid_json['Countries']
for value in countries:
    b = f"Country: {value['Country']} NewConfirmed: {value['NewConfirmed']} NewDeaths: {value['NewDeaths']}"
    print(b)
```

The print should look like this

```
Country: Afghanistan NewConfirmed: 262 NewDeaths: 1
Country: Albania NewConfirmed: 13 NewDeaths: 0
Country: Algeria NewConfirmed: 198 NewDeaths: 6
Country: Andorra NewConfirmed: 0 NewDeaths: 0
Country: Angola NewConfirmed: 0 NewDeaths: 0
Country: Antigua and Barbuda NewConfirmed: 0 NewDeaths: 0
Country: Argentina NewConfirmed: 263 NewDeaths: 10
Country: Armenia NewConfirmed: 189 NewDeaths: 5
Country: Australia NewConfirmed: 10 NewDeaths: 1
Country: Austria NewConfirmed: 41 NewDeaths: 0
Country: Azerbaijan NewConfirmed: 136 NewDeaths: 3
```

Comment: Thank you Harven and Scott for your help !

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use pandas dataframe constructor with a key of 'Countries' to your resulting json from requests.get:

```
import requests    
covid_get = requests.get("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
df = pd.DataFrame(covid_get.json()['Countries'])

df.head()
```

Output:

```
       Country CountryCode         Slug  NewConfirmed  TotalConfirmed  \
0  Afghanistan          AF  afghanistan           262            6664   
1      Albania          AL      albania            13             946   
2      Algeria          DZ      algeria           198            7019   
3      Andorra          AD      andorra             0             761   
4       Angola          AO       angola             0              48   

   NewDeaths  TotalDeaths  NewRecovered  TotalRecovered                  Date  
0          1          169            33             778  2020-05-19T02:30:42Z  
1          0           31             1             715  2020-05-19T02:30:42Z  
2          6          548            98            3507  2020-05-19T02:30:42Z  
3          0           51             2             617  2020-05-19T02:30:42Z  
4          0            2             0              17  2020-05-19T02:30:42Z
```

Comment: beat me to the punch